# Calculate the hours minutes and days of difference between two date and hours

Tags: php, datetime

I have a PHP and MySQL code that should calculate the hours minutes and days of difference between two date and hours. It works well, just adding 20 hours and 20 minutes more than normal. And I remove the DATE part and put the date and time manually, it works fine.

I don't understand what happens.

```
    $fecha = $row["fecha"];
        $data= $row["hora"];
$start = strtotime("$fecha $hora"); 


$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$currentTime = date("H:i:s");
$currentDate =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($currentDate .$currentTime));

$end = strtotime("$currentDate"); 



$totaltime = ($end - $start)  ; 

$hours = intval($totaltime / 3600);   
$seconds_remain = ($totaltime - ($hours * 3600)); 

$minutes = intval($seconds_remain / 60);   
$seconds = ($seconds_remain - ($minutes * 60));
$statusfichaje= $row["status"];
if ($statusfichaje == Start){echo '<td>Trabajando'.$hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds.' </td>';}else{echo '<td>'. $row["status"] .'</td>';}
```

### Edit

start 2019-12-29 21:27:50 . end 2019-12-31 0:51:50 = 47:51:16

As you can see it calculates badly.

Comment: `if ($statusfichaje == Start)` < That "Start" is interpreted as a constant. It either needs to be a variable or as text wrapped in quotes. Enable error reporting.

Comment: Your code to generate `$end` should just be simplified to `$end = strtotime('now');`

Comment: checked, it doesn't work either. it's putting me 20 more hours

Comment: We don't use [solved] title hacks here - instead there is a question acceptance system. Click the tick mark adjacent to the answer that most helped you, so that it turns green. (Self answers are welcome, though I prefer to accept other people's answers if they got me most of the way towards a solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example like this would do the job :

```
$mydatetime = new DateTime();
$datefromdb = new DateTime('2018-03-05 10:10:00');
$interval = $mydatetime->diff($datefromdb);
$date_count = $interval->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');
echo $date_count;
```

This is your code it should work

```
$fecha = $row["fecha"];
$data= $row["hora"];
$start = strtotime("$fecha $data"); 


$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
$currentTime = date("H:i:s");
$currentDate =  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($currentDate .$currentTime));

$end = strtotime("$currentDate"); 



$totaltime = ($end - $start)  ; 

$hours = intval($totaltime / 3600);   
$seconds_remain = ($totaltime - ($hours * 3600)); 

$minutes = intval($seconds_remain / 60);   
$seconds = ($seconds_remain - ($minutes * 60));
$statusfichaje= $row["status"];
if ($statusfichaje == $start){echo '<td>Trabajando'.$hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds.' </td>';}else{echo '<td>'. $row["status"] .'</td>';}
```

Comment: With your example, it happens the same way it puts me 20 extra hours.

Comment: $statusfichaje == start) this will give you true result in answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the string.

```
  $data= $row["hora"];
```

and I use this:

```
$start = strtotime("$fecha $hora");
```

And don't take the hours and calculate only for days.

Comment: $start = strtotime("$fecha $hora");  copied my answer