# Subtracting hours and minutes from input fields

Tags: php

I have a form that has five input fields:

```
name="MultiRoomFromDate"  //outputs the date in the following format "d-m-Y"
name="MultiRoomFromTimeH" // has a dropdown of "00" to "23"
name="MultiRoomFromTimeM" // has a dropdown of "00" to "59"


<select name="MultiFromDisplayTimeH" id="MultiFromDisplayTimeH" class="FormTime">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="3600">1</option>
    <option value="7220">2</option>
    <option value="10800">3</option>
    <option value="14400">4</option>
 </select>

<select name="MultiFromDisplayTimeM" id="MultiFromDisplayTimeM" class="FormTime">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="900">15</option>
    <option value="1800">30</option>
    <option value="2700">45</option>
</select>
```

If I select the "MultiRoomFromDate" as 26-01-2020" and the MultiRoomFromTimeH as "09" and the MultiRoomFromTimeM as "00" and the select the "MultiFromDisplayTimeH" as "01"and the "MultiFromDisplayTimeM" as "00" and submit the form the output is:

```
FromDate = MultiRoomFromDate; //26-1-2020
FromHours = MultiRoomFromTimeH; //09
FromMins = MultiRoomFromTimeM; //00
DisplayHours = MultiFromDisplayTimeH; //3600
DisplayMins = MultiFromDisplayTimeM; //0
```

What I need to do is output the "FromDate, FromHours, FromMins" **MINUS** the "DisplayHours" and "DisplayMins" as Y-m-d H:i.

This is what I have been working with:

```
$MultiRoomFromDate = trim($_POST['MultiRoomFromDate']);
$MultiFromDisplayTimeH = trim($_POST['MultiFromDisplayTimeH']);
$MultiFromDisplayTimeM = trim($_POST['MultiFromDisplayTimeM']);

$FromdateStamp = strtotime($MultiRoomFromDate);
$TodateStamp = strtotime($MultiRoomToDate );
$DisplayTime = $FromTimeStamp - $FromDisplayHours - $FromDisplayMins;
$DisplayDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i", $DisplayTime);

$RoomFromTime = $MultiRoomFromTimeH.":".$MultiRoomFromTimeM;

if(!empty($MultiFromDisplayTimeH)) {
    $DisplayTime1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-". $MultiFromDisplayTimeH." hours", strtotime($MultiRoomFromDate." ". $RoomFromTime))); 
} 

if(!empty($MultiFromDisplayTimeM)) {
    $DisplayTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-". $MultiFromDisplayTimeM." minutes", strtotime($DisplayTime1))); 
}   

if(empty($MultiFromDisplayTimeH) && empty($MultiFromDisplayTimeM)){
    $DisplayTime = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($DisplayDateTime));
}
```

Also tried:

```
$t = $MultiFromDisplayTimeH + $MultiFromDisplayTimeM;
$RoomFromTimeStamp = strtotime($MultiRoomFromDate);
$h = $RoomFromTimeStamp - $t;
$DisplayTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$h);
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: See this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538259/12232340 first function in answer will give result you are asking

Comment: Where is your attempt to perform this calculation with php?  It appear that you want someone to do your work for you.  Volunteers are meant to help you to fix your issue not do your work for free.  Is your desired output from the sample input: `2020-01-26 08:00`?

Comment: @mickmackusa hi, I will edit my post to include what I have tried and get back to you. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @DCJones I have posted an answer, then deleted it.  I will undelete my answer once you have completed your question by including your coding attempt and confirming the exact desired result from your sample data.

Comment: @mickmackusa Hi, I have included my attempt to get the code to work but as you can see it does not work which is why I asked the question. I agree I should have included it with my original post.

Comment: Hi all, completely rewrote my code and I have resolved the issue using:     $DisplayTime = $FromTimeStamp - $FromDisplayHours - $FromDisplayMins;
$DisplayDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i", $DisplayTime);. Thanks to all for looking at my post

Answer (score 2):

First, simplify your select option syntax by removing the `value` attributes -- it only makes your markup harder to comprehend at a glance and it will not be necessary for the datetime calculation that I will later demonstrate.  I also think simpler field names would be beneficial.

```
<select name="subtractHours" class="FormTime">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
 </select>

<select name="subtractMinutes" class="FormTime">
    <option>0</option>
    <option>15</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>45</option>
</select>
```

Then, use PHP's datetime class to:

1. Initialize a datetime object from your date/time values
2. Subtract the submitted amount of time
3. Adjusted datetime string into the desired format.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LTMk8))

```
$fromDate = '26-1-2020';
$fromHours = '09';
$fromMins = '00';
$subtractHours = '1';
$subtractMins = '0';

$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', "{$fromDate} {$fromHours}:{$fromMins}:00");
$date->sub(new DateInterval("PT{$subtractHours}H{$subtractMins}M"));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Output:

```
2020-01-26 08:00
```

I added the `:00` as seconds to the object for stability/consistency in case you wanted to insert the full datetime stamp into your database (which will require `Y-m-d H:i:s` format).

---

The above will process just as well when the time subtraction results in losing a day.  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OtjU0))

```
$fromDate = '25-1-2020';
$fromHours = '01';
$fromMins = '30';
$subtractHours = '6';  // don't bother with 3600 precalculation
$subtractMins = '45';

// Output: 2020-01-24 18:45
```

Answer (score -1):

I completely rewrote my code and I have now resolved the issue by using the following code:

```
$DisplayTime = $FromTimeStamp - $FromDisplayHours - $FromDisplayMins;
echo "DISPLAYTIME 1 ".$DisplayTime."<br/>";
$DisplayDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i", $DisplayTime);
```

Comment: Code-only answer are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers; they also reduce the chances of search engines finding the page because plain English keywords are often missing from code blocks.